# How to get the MSISDN on firefox OS

Tags: javascript, firefox, manifest, firefox-os, msisdn

I'm developing a web application for Firefox OS, and I need to get the MSISDN. I'm using a privileged app.

here is my manifest :

```
{
"version": "0.1",

"type": "privileged",
"permissions": {
"mobileid": {
"description": "Needed for MSISDN"
}
},
"name": "My app",
"description": "My app",
"launch_path": "/index.html",
"icons": {
"16": "/assets/icons/icon16.png",
"48": "/assets/icons/icon48.png",
"128": "/assets/icons/icon128.png"
},
"developer": {
"name": "YasserB.",
"url": ""
},
"default_locale": "fr"
}
```

I'm using firefox OS Mobile id permission.

and I'm using that code to get the MSISDN

```
var msisdn = navigator.mozMobileConnection.iccInfo.msisdn;
```

i'm getting an error :

```
TypeError: navigator.mozMobileConnection is undefined
```

Comment: Same error if you try : `window.navigator.mozMobileConnection.iccInfo.msisdn;` ?

Comment: Yes same error, I've already tried that

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the [MobileID](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/MobileIdentity) API, but the [MobileConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MozMobileConnection) one (which btw is for certified apps only) in your code.

Adding the `mobileid` permission to your manifest you should be able to call `navigator.getMobileIdAssertion()`. Note that this API requires the user to accept sharing the phone number with your application.

Comment: Thanks ! and how it's possible to get the MSISDN ??